# SSRS Query Based Parameters Not Refreshing

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am having a problem getting query-based parameters to refresh in SSRS when the View Report or Refresh button is clicked.  To illustrate the problem, I created a report with 2 parameters.  1 parameter is set to get the timestamp Now() using the SSRS function.  The other parameter is set to get the value GETDATE() from a SQL Server database query.  When I view the report, both parameters accurately get the timestamp.  When I hit the View Report button or Refresh, neither parameter refreshes.  The only way I can get the timestamps to refresh is to re-open the page up in a new browser.  Is there anyway to get these timestamps to update without having to open a new page/session?  Thanks!

Comment: I assume that your using the current date as the problem is merely for illustration purposes?  You're not really passing the current date into a report as a parameter?

Comment: @AnnL. Correct! It was just the easiest way to illustrate the issue I am having. I am actually running a querying against a SQL Server database, setting the results to a parameter, and then feeding that parameter into an Oracle database query. When the user hits "View Report" or "Refresh", the SQL Server results may have changed, but it is not refresh the parameter values. Which is what I was able to illustrate with the datetime example.

Comment: When you view the report, are you doing so in the Web Report control?  In Report Manager?  Somewhere else?

Comment: I have viewed it both in preview mode inside SSRS and also deployed it and viewed it from the Report Viewer link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix: Build a main report with no parameters. Embed a subreport to your report. In the subreport, build a parameter called RandomTime. In the main report, go to Subreport Properties and feed the parameter RandomTime with the Value =Now(). To properly refresh all of the query based parameters in the subreport everytime you hit refresh, they must depend on RandomTime. The easiest way I found to do this add a column to the SQL query like this SLECT @RandomTime AS DummyColumn. It ensures that the query will repull and all the parameters will refresh everytime the refresh button is clicked

Comment: Perfect! This is the workaround I was looking for. I used random number instead of Now() because of datatype issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do this: Create a master report and add your report as a sub report. Make a dataset on the master that runs your sql query. Then, pass the result into the sub report parameter as an expression.

```
Example--- =First(Fields!YourValue.Value, "DataSet1") ---
```

Comment: Yes, I tried the 'Always Refresh' setting both in preview mode and when deployed, and it did not fix the problem.

Comment: I just made a ssrs report in report builder with one parameter with value =now(). I dragged it to the report and ran the report. Every time I refresh the date changes. Try this, does it refresh?

Comment: No!  I wonder why it is working for you and not me.  I set Data Type to Text (Date/Time behavior not working for me).  Visibility = Visible.  I specified an available value with Label =Now() and Value =Now(). I set default value to =Now(). Under advanced I put Always Refresh.  I have a textbox in the report set to [@Time1] (my parameter name).  Is that exactly what you did?  It is not working for me.

Comment: @esquire:  How are you running the reports in your test cases?  From the web, in Visual Studio, or in the separate report builder?  That might account for why the two of you are seeing different behaviors.

Comment: @AnnL. I was running in report builder. I looked at the web control and the parameter will not update due to how it is built. I would either suggest using a report variable to update datetime. If you are determined to get it working with the parameter you will need to make your own UI so that the parameters refresh every time a report is refreshed.

Comment: @esquire: My actual use case is not a datetime stamp.  It was just the easiest way to illustrate the issue I am having.  I am actually running a querying against a SQL Server database, setting the results to a parameter, and then feeding that parameter into an Oracle database query.  When the user hits "View Report" or "Refresh", the SQL Server results may have changed, but it is not refresh the parameter values.  Which is what I was able to illustrate with the datetime example.  When you say build my own UI, do you mean in asp.net?  Is there anything I can do to the SSRS code? Thxs!

Comment: Do this:  Create a master report and add your report as a sub report. Make a dataset on the master that runs your sql query. Then, pass the result into the sub report parameter as an expression. Example--- =First(Fields!YourValue.Value, "DataSet1") ---

Comment: @esquire: I like your suggestion.  It is a multi-value parameter.  Any idea how to feed that forward?  I know they need to be comma separated but =Join((Fields!MyValue.Value, "DateSet1"),",") does not work.

Comment: Try this: =Split(Join(Parameters!Your_Parameter_Name.Value, ”,”), ”,”)   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793171/how-to-pass-multiple-values-to-a-multivalued-paramter-in-ssrs

Comment: That won't work because now you are referencing a parameter, which we have already proved is not updating properly. Your suggestion about using a field pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Fix: Build a main report with no parameters.  Embed a subreport to your report.  In the subreport, build a parameter called RandomTime.  In the main report, go to Subreport Properties and feed the parameter RandomTime with the Value =Now(). To properly refresh all of the query based parameters in the subreport everytime you hit refresh, they must depend on RandomTime.  The easiest way I found to do this add a column to the SQL query like this SLECT @RandomTime AS DummyColumn.  It ensures that the query will repull and all the parameters will refresh everytime the refresh button is clicked.